# Problemas com Promisse: Promisse[Object]

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize-js

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e estou fazendo consultas ao banco de dados com um modelo pré-definido, estou tentando usar uma função assíncrona para guardar o valor desta consulta em uma variável.
Abaixo segue o código que estou tentando implementar:

```
const Bloco1 = require('../../../models/Bloco1')

var consulta = Bloco1.findOne({ order: [['createdAt', 'desc']] }).then(result => {
    return result
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(`ERRO: ${err}`)
})

console.log(consulta)
```

## Retorno do console:

```
Promise [Object] {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined
}
Executing (default): SELECT `Bomba`, `Cisterna`, `Caixa_da_Agua`, `Temperatura`, `Pressao`, `Banco_de_Dados`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `bloco1s` AS `bloco1s` ORDER BY `bloco1s`.`createdAt` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

## Dei um `console.log(result)` e me retornou o seguinte resultado:

```
    Executing (default): SELECT `Bomba`, `Cisterna`, `Caixa_da_Agua`, `Temperatura`, `Pressao`, `Banco_de_Dados`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `bloco1s` AS `bloco1s` ORDER BY `bloco1s`.`createdAt` DESC LIMIT 1;
    bloco1s {
      dataValues: {
        Bomba: 0,
        Cisterna: 1,
        Caixa_da_Agua: 1,
        Temperatura: 22,
        Pressao: 15,
        Banco_de_Dados: 'sim',
        createdAt: 2020-03-03T15:05:09.000Z,
        updatedAt: 2020-03-03T15:05:09.000Z
      },
      _previousDataValues: {
        Bomba: 0,
        Cisterna: 1,
        Caixa_da_Agua: 1,
        Temperatura: 22,
        Pressao: 15,
        Banco_de_Dados: 'sim',
        createdAt: 2020-03-03T15:05:09.000Z,
        updatedAt: 2020-03-03T15:05:09.000Z
      }
```

**Como guardo este resulta dessa consulta em uma variável sem ser em um objeto JSON? alguém pode me ajudar?**

**OBS: preciso que seja dessa maneira pois vou utlizar ela em outros locais da aplicação**

Comment: `consulta.then( dados => { use os dados aqui } )`

Comment: desculpa @bfavaretto eu não fui claro no final da pergunta, eu entendi a sua resposta, porém esses dados irão mudar de tempos em tempos, por isso eu gostaria de guardar essa "consulta" em uma variável pois irei utilizar em outros locais

Comment: tentei fazer dessa maneira e "acho" que deu certo fiz o seguinte: `console.log(consulta.then(dados => { dados: dados }))`

Comment: Você tem a opção de usar de forma assíncrona.

Comment: Pois é @LucasBrogni, porém eu sou péssimo com async await ou Promisse, a minha grande dificuldade é entender no código aonde esperar um retorno, por isso que estou travado nesta parte, mas agradeço muito quem puder me ajudar a entender o problema, não quero que façam pra mim, só quero entender pra resolver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso utilizar `async/await` for uma opção, podes fazer assim:

```
const Bloco1 = require('../../../models/Bloco1')
async function getBloco() { 
   try { 
     let consulta = await Bloco1.findOne({ order: [['createdAt', 'desc']] }); 
     console.log(consulta)
     return consulta; 
   } 
   catch(err) { 
      console.log(`ERRO: ${err}`)
   }
}
```

Contudo vale salientar que terias que ter uma função para definir como async...

Bastaria então chamar essa função e estaria pronto.

Comment: valeu vou tentar aqui e já te dou uma resposta, muito obrigado msm!

Comment: funcionou! muito obrigado msm!